# How to quote column names on the commandline of fbexport

Tags: firebird, fbexport

As the title says, how am I going to deal with a column name in FBExport that look like a keyword?

this is how my statement looks like:

```
-Q "SELECT a.ID, a.USERID, a.`WHEN`, a.INOUT FROM ATTENDANT a"
```

then I get this error:

```
Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 26
WHEN
```

When I use

```
"WHEN"


Error: Switches must begin with -
```

tried 'When'

```
-Q "SELECT a.ID, a.USERID, a.'WHEN', a.INOUT FROM ATTENDANT a;"
SQL Message : -104
Invalid token

Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 26
'WHEN'

Error: Switches must begin with -
```

What are the correct escape characters?

Comment: did you try to enclose the query in single quotes? Then you should be able to use the (correct) double quotes inside the query string

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes I tried every kind of quotes ' , ", `, ´, all doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't know FBExport, but I guess the easiest thing would be to create a view that renames that column.

Comment: Firebird uses double quotes **if the database is dialect 3**, however the problem seems to be that you did not escape the double quote in the commandline option., try `\"WHEN\"`.

Comment: I meant: `-Q 'SELECT a.ID, a.USERID, a."WHEN", a.INOUT FROM ATTENDANT a;'`

Answer (score 1):

For dialect 3 database, Firebird allows quoting object names using double quotes (`"<objectname>"`). Be aware that quoting object names makes them case sensitive, so `"WHEN"` is not the same as `"when"`. If your database is dialect 1 then this is not possible, and you should first convert your database to dialect 3.

However the problem this is a command line option, meaning that

```
-Q "SELECT a.ID, a.USERID, a."WHEN", a.INOUT FROM ATTENDANT a"
```

Is split by your shell to the arguments:

1. `-Q`
2. `SELECT a.ID, a.USERID, a.`
3. `WHEN`
4. `, a.INOUT FROM ATTENDANT a`

While you want:

1. `-Q`
2. `SELECT a.ID, a.USERID, a."WHEN", a.INOUT FROM ATTENDANT a`

To achieve that, you need to escape the double quote inside the second argument, so:

```
-Q "SELECT a.ID, a.USERID, a.\"WHEN\", a.INOUT FROM ATTENDANT a"
```

or - as indicated by a_horse_with_no_name in the comments - wrap the argument in single quotes:

```
-Q 'SELECT a.ID, a.USERID, a."WHEN", a.INOUT FROM ATTENDANT a'
```

This doesn't really have to do with Firebird or FBExport, but is a result of how your shell (eg bash) parses commandline arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone else is dealing with the external access to the Firebird database from Safescan `TimeAttenedant`

It was a little bit stupid from Safescan to name a column `WHEN` because this is a keyword in Firebird.

In the context of an insert statement, I have no success with a column list like:

```
insert into attendant (ID, USERID, DEVICEID, WHEN, INOUT, VERIFYMODE, WORKCODE) values (1092, 1, 1, '28.08.2017 08:00', 0, 4, 3);
```

"WHEN", \"WHEN\", \'WHEN\', ... no success

Remedy - Insert all data without column list, ex:

```
insert into attendant values (1034, 2, 1, '28.08.2017 08:00', 0, 4, null, null, null, null, null, 3);
```

Query is much easier: `select * from attendant;`