# Alias containing space in SQL using firebird database

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have an SQL statement and I would like to have an alias with a space. For example:

```
select name as User name from users;
```

I tried different syntaxes but it fails.

```
select name as "User name" from users;
select name as 'User name' from users;
select name as {User name} from users;
select name as [User name] from users;
```

database version: **Firebird 2.5**

Help me please

Comment: Are you running these statements directly from the command line?

Comment: If you were running this on dialect 3 from the command line, then you might have had an option to make this work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574477/how-to-quote-column-names-on-the-commandline-of-fbexport

Comment: i running it in command line and in IBExpert.

Comment: You are using `2.x` so I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I think the easiest way out of this is to heed Gordon's warning and just avoid spaces.  If you follow the link I pasted above, it appears that the `2.x` dialog does not support double escaping, so you might be out of luck even if you wanted to do it.

Comment: `"User name"`  should work - that's standard SQL.

Comment: should work in modern SQL dialect, just run `select mon$sql_dialect "диалект языка" from mon$Database` over 2.5.x.26952 server with 2.1.7 client library in IBExpert - works like a charm. And Dialect 1 is no longer supported, move away from it

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not sure what you meant with _"the 2.x dialog does not support double escaping"_, Firebird has always supported quoted identifiers, but only in dialect 3 databases. This was introduced in Interbase 6, the version that Firebird (0.9) was forked from. The OP is apparently using a legacy dialect 1 database. The dialect version has nothing to do with the Firebird version itself.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Perhaps I misread your previous answer, apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise you to simply stop wanting the space -- it is a hassle to deal with delimited identifiers in any database.

But, as the [documentation](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-structure-identifiers.html) explains, Firebird does not necessarily support them:

> - Delimited identifiers are available in Dialect 3 only. For more details on dialects, see [SQL Dialect](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-background.html#fblangref25-structure-dialects).